# Knowledge of electronic devices is hard to learn？

Tags: integrated-circuit

I want to learn about more about electronics，but I don't know where to start, because there are too many electronic devices out there. If I can, I am willing to learn integrated circuits first, but I don't have enough resources at my disposal.

Comment: Reading a book about electronics? Or google... better not start with integrated circuits first, that would be like wanting to buy a sky scraper while you cannot build a house.

Comment: Proper capitalisation, spacing, etc. is important, please don't ignore them.

Comment: You can start by buying kits for hobbyists. Learn to solder and assemble  them, then try to understand what each component does. Of course, you can start with kits for experiments using a breadboard (solderless). Learn the basics of direct current and alternating current.

Comment: This isn't really a question about electronics, it's more a question on how to go about learning stuff. But as your current goal is to learn electronics, I guess this site is as good as any, and I feel that Alexander von Wernherr's answer has got you covered.

Comment: you are right，This is not a question about electronics.Maybe I just want to get encouragement from you that have professionals.

Comment: Look up some of the Don Lancaster Cookbooks.  They are old, but well written, with many example circuits explained.

Comment: Visit an audio store, and get copies of schematics of audio amplifiers. Learn how those work.

Answer (score 6):

Libraries are a good place to start.

You can read yourself into the basics of electronics, like Ohm's Law, capacities, inductances.

From there, set yourself easy targets, what you want to accomplish. Start off with simple circuits with one or two fets and go from there.

If you're stuck, write *specific* questions here @ee.se. Draw a schematic and describe what you want to achieve and why you think it doesn't work out.

There's tons of free SW out there like LTspice for trying to build stuff, without actually having to solder something.

So:

- Read
- Understand
- Try
- Ask (here)

Comment: yes，thank you ，i will listen 。Because my previous major was not electronics, I felt very hard to learn. I know the basic functions of some parts, but I don’t know anything about the circuit.

Comment: Library? What’s that?!

Comment: @BlairFonville Some sort of analog Kindle

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your goal. If you want to be a professional, you have to go in detail. However, I assume you want to 'make' things. Than the easiest way is to buy a hobby/learning kit, even for kids.

Also, since you want to use ICs, you also might want to learn about microcontrollers, and buy an Arduino kit. The advantage is these are well documented, and plenty of examples/help available on internet.

Btw, I started with Arduino without knowing much about electronic components and faced the same problems as you. But you don't need to know that much about electronics to start, although reading a book about electronics will help a lot.

But start with simple things: how to blink a led, how to use a switch, a breadboard, learn when to use resistors/capacitors etc, than start with simple ICs.